# i need to write a code for the golomb sequence but i only get the answer and not the whole sequence

Tags: scheme

I need to code the golomb rank, this is my code:

```lisp
(define ( golomb n)
    (if (= n 1)
        n
        (+ 1 (golomb (- n (golomb (golomb (- n 1))))))))
    
(define (golomb-reeks n)
     (cond ((= 1 n) (display n))
           ((< 1 n) (display (golomb n)))))
```

but when I do `(golomb-reeks 20)` it gives me the answer 8 and not 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 .....

What do I need to change in my code in order to get the whole rank and not the last rank?

Comment: All `(golomb n)` does is to produce one number. Are you confusing "output" as in returning a value from a function with "output" as in printing something?